# Динамическое программирование в поиске чисел

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык, динамическое-программирование

На всех n-значных числах нужно посчитать кол-во таких чисел у которых **любые две соседние цифры** имеют разность по модулю <= 1 
Допустим есть функция f(n) = кол-ву этих чисел 
Если для f(1) = 0, таких нет, для f(2) таких 8*3+2 (т.к. на промежутке 10-99 на всех десятках есть по 3 таких числа, кроме числа начинающегося с 9 там их 2 т.к. оно крайнее, например 10,11,12,21,22,23,32,33,34 ... 98,99.)
Получается что `f(n) = f(n-1)*10 (т.к. если к изначально подходящему числу подставить в конец любую цифру, то оно все равно удовлетворяет условию) + ..что то еще..`
Долго не могу сложить этот пазл, как посчитать кол-во следующих n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заполняем табличку. F - количество чисел длиной N, заканчивающихся цифрой L:

```
  F(N, L) {L=1..8} = F(N-1, L-1) + F(N-1, L) + F(N-1, L+1)
  F(N, 0) = F(N-1, 0) + F(N-1, 1)
  F(N, 9) = F(N-1, 9) + F(N-1, 8)
  F(1, 0) = 0
  F(1, K>0) = 1
```

Comment: Имеется ввиду таблица как матрица N на 10?
т.е. для каждого i  (1 < i <= n) по 10 цифр(включая ноль)

Comment: да, всё верно..